# Empty div with red border is visible as a red line - can I hide it only with CSS?

Tags: css

I have a div which in which errors will be represented. My problem is that because it has a red border, it will be displayed as an empty line even when the div is empty (there are no errors). I don't like this behavior; I'd prefer the div to be completely invisible when it is empty.

Also, I don't want to do that with javascript—is it possible to hide the border when the div is empty only with CSS?

Comment: Please your code for better understanding

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Here is one possible solution using [empty-cells](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/empty-cells):

**CSS**

```
.error {
    display:table-cell;
    empty-cells:hide;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="error"><!-- I am empty --></div>
<div class="error">Error'd!</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/At6Sp/

Comment: This still accounts for borders though. Even without padding, the borders are there, just invisible. It's sort of distracting. :P

Comment: If the div is on its own line or similar, no one would notice an extra 2px of line height. There are plenty of places you could use a construction like this in a perfectly valid manner. If he's trying to put it between two items, you're correct-- this would be distracting.

Comment: Though +1 because I didn't know about `empty-cells`. You should probably include a link to the spec on that.

Comment: I see this note: `Note: IE8 supports the empty-cells property only if a !DOCTYPE is specified.`. Do you have one?

Answer (score 11):

check out this [CSS3 pseudoclass `:empty`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-empty)

```
​div{
    border:1px solid red
}

div:empty{
    display:none
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nWRJb/1/

Comment: +1, but no IE support at all means this really isn't a viable real-world solution :(

Comment: but at least it's a step forward to modernity. also, you can use http://selectivizr.com/ coupled with a JS library of your choice so it'll work in IE

Comment: @Interrobang OP define css3 in his tag which means he want support in modern browsers

Comment: @sandeep: While I too would love to live in your world, in which Internet Explorer does not exist, the reality is that it still controls over half the market in most countries :P

Comment: @sandeep: I added the css3 tag, which may have been a mistake since he may not be looking for that, but I was interested in a modern method as I'm sure others are.

Comment: @Interrobang even though IE has the highest share, how many of those are IE 6's and 7's? http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201111-201201-bar - not much.

Comment: @Interrobang apparently you missed the 3rd comment and someone added CSS3. just taking a setp into the future. anyways, it's up to the OP to decide which is more convenient.

Comment: I'm definitely in favor of supporting modern browsers first and foremost. OP stated he didn't want any Javascript (selectivizr is nice though) and I don't think you can escape supporting IE otherwise. Anyways, choices are good!

Answer (score 3):

BEST way is to control it from server side and DON'T display if its empty.
Otherwise you can use :empty selector but its support in IE is not solid.

And yes, if you use jquery then you'll be fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('div:empty').remove(); });
```

Comment: +1, I don't get why he just can't prevent the element from being written at all if there aren't any errors.