# border around label when there is no text

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a very simple Question,

I have a Label that appears whenever there is an error on the page. The label has a red border around it.
The label border shows up even when there is no text in the label.

How I can make the border invisible (of course by CSS) when there is no text ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post code of your Lable TAG and its associated style, so we can analyze better

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408294/empty-div-with-red-border-is-visible-as-a-red-line-can-i-hide-it-only-with-css?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [:empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) selector of css3.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bHF7r/)**

```
label:empty
{
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

You would probably need give some `height` and `width` to the label and set the `position:absolute` in order to give some space to empty label.

Comment: Thanks, It works, but not for IE, 
I have to make it compatible with IE8, (request by client!)

Comment: You can use the javascript or jQuery for that, is that possible for you?

Comment: You are welcome, you would need something like, $('label:empty').addClass('classforborder');